# improving python code in Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: python, performance

I've written a Monte Carlo simulation for a "2d active ising model" and I'm trying to improve the runtime.

What my code does:
I create a matrix for the number of particles (r) and one for the magnetisation for each spot (rgrid and mgrid). the spins of the particles can be either -1/1 so the magnetisation ranges from [-r, r] in steps of 2.

Then a random spot and a random particle is chosen(+1 or -1). Since the probability depends on the number of positive/negative particles at each place I create 2 arrays and zip them so I can get the fitting number of positive particles, i.e. [(-3, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)].
With 3 particles I can have a magnetisation of (-3, -1, 1, 3) which has (0, 1, 2, 3) +1 particles.

After that I calculate the probabilities for the spot and choose an action: spinflip, jump up/down, jump left/right, do nothing.
Now I have to move the particle (or not) and change the magnet./density for the 2 spots (and check for periodic boundary conditions).

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cProfile

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

m = 10  # zeilen, spalten
j = 1000 # finale zeit
r = 3  # platzdichte
b = 1.6  # beta
e = 0.9  # epsilon

M = m * m  # platzanzahl
N = M * r  # teilchenanzahl
dt = 1 / (4 * np.exp(b))  # delta-t
i = 0

rgrid = r * np.ones((m, m)).astype(int)  # dichte-matrix, rho = n(+) + n(-)
magrange = np.arange(-r, r + 1, 2)  # mögliche magnetisierungen [a, b), schrittweite
mgrid = np.random.choice(magrange, (m, m))  # magnetisierungs-matrix m = n(+) - (n-)


def flip():
    mgrid[math.trunc(x / m), x % m] -= 2 * spin

def up():
    y = x - m
    if y < 0:  # periodische randbedingung hoch
        y += m * m
    x1 = math.trunc(x / m)
    x2 = x % m
    y1 = math.trunc(y / m)
    y2 = y % m
    rgrid[x1, x2] -= 1  # [zeile, spalte] masse -1
    rgrid[y1, y2] += 1  # [zeile, spalte] masse +1
    mgrid[x1, x2] -= spin  # [zeile, spalte] spinänderung alter platz
    mgrid[y1, y2] += spin  # [zeile, spalte] spinänderung neuer platz

def down():
    y = x + m
    if y >= m * m:  # periodische randbedingung unten
        y -= m * m
    x1 = math.trunc(x / m)
    x2 = x % m
    y1 = math.trunc(y / m)
    y2 = y % m
    rgrid[x1, x2] -= 1
    rgrid[y1, y2] += 1
    mgrid[x1, x2] -= spin
    mgrid[y1, y2] += spin

def left():
    y = x - 1
    if math.trunc(y / m) < math.trunc(x / m):  # periodische randbedingung links
        y += m
    x1 = math.trunc(x / m)
    x2 = x % m
    y1 = math.trunc(y / m)
    y2 = y % m
    rgrid[x1, x2] -= 1
    rgrid[y1, y2] += 1
    mgrid[x1, x2] -= spin
    mgrid[y1, y2] += spin

def right():
    y = x + 1
    if math.trunc(y / m) > math.trunc(x / m):  # periodische randbedingung rechts
        y -= m
    x1 = math.trunc(x / m)
    x2 = x % m
    y1 = math.trunc(y / m)
    y2 = y % m
    rgrid[x1, x2] -= 1
    rgrid[y1, y2] += 1
    mgrid[x1, x2] -= spin
    mgrid[y1, y2] += spin


while i < j:

    # 1. platz aussuchen
    x = np.random.randint(M)  # wähle zufälligen platz aus

    if rgrid.item(x) != 0:

        i += dt / N

        # 2. teilchen aussuchen
        li1 = np.arange(-abs(rgrid.item(x)), abs(rgrid.item(x)) + 1, 2)
        li2 = np.arange(0, abs(rgrid.item(x)) + 1)
        li3 = zip(li1, li2)  # list1 und list2 als tupel in list3

        results = [item[1] for item in li3 if item[0] == mgrid.item(x)]  # gebe 2. element von tupel aus für passende magnetisierung
        num = int(''.join(map(str, results)))  # wandle listeneintrag in int um
        spin = 1.0 if np.random.random() < num / rgrid.item(x) else -1.0

        # 3. ereignis aussuchen
        p = np.random.random()
        p1 = np.exp(- spin * b * mgrid.item(x) / rgrid.item(x)) * dt  # flip
        p2 = dt  # hoch
        p3 = dt  # runter
        p4 = (1 - spin * e) * dt  # links
        p5 = (1 + spin * e) * dt  # rechts
        p6 = 1 - (4 + p1) * dt  # nichts


        if p < p6:
            continue
        elif p < p6 + p1:
            flip()
            continue
        elif p < p6 + p1 + p2:
            up()
            continue
        elif p < p6 + p1 + p2 + p3:
            down()
            continue
        elif p < p6 + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4:
            left()
            continue
        else:
            right()
            continue

pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='cumtime')
```

what i already did to speed things up:

- used cProfile to see that the random.choice i was using was terribly slow and changed that to the if-conditions for the spin and the probabilities p
- installed cython and used `import pyximport; pyximport.install()` to create a compiled cython file. this gave no improvement and after checking the `cython -a script.py` i see that i need more static variables to gain some improvements.

running `cProfile` now shows me this:

```
188939207 function calls in 151.834 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  5943639   10.582    0.000   40.678    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  5943639   32.543    0.000   37.503    0.000 script.py:107(<listcomp>)
  5943639    4.722    0.000   30.096    0.000 numeric.py:1905(array_str)
  8276949   25.852    0.000   25.852    0.000 {method 'randint' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
  5943639   11.855    0.000   25.374    0.000 arrayprint.py:381(wrapper)
 11887279   14.403    0.000   14.403    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
 80651998   13.559    0.000   13.559    0.000 {method 'item' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
  5943639    8.427    0.000    9.364    0.000 arrayprint.py:399(array2string)
 11887278    8.817    0.000    8.817    0.000 {method 'random_sample' of 'mtrand.RandomState' objects}
   579016    7.351    0.000    7.866    0.000 script.py:79(right)
   300021    3.669    0.000    3.840    0.000 script.py:40(up)
   152838    1.950    0.000    2.086    0.000 script.py:66(left)
 17830917    1.910    0.000    1.910    0.000 {built-in method builtins.abs}
   176346    1.147    0.000    1.217    0.000 script.py:37(flip)
  5943639    1.131    0.000    1.131    0.000 {method 'discard' of 'set' objects}
  5943639    1.054    0.000    1.054    0.000 {built-in method _thread.get_ident}
  5943639    1.010    0.000    1.010    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
  5943639    0.961    0.000    0.961    0.000 {built-in method builtins.id}
  3703804    0.892    0.000    0.892    0.000 {built-in method math.trunc}
```

I use `join` to get the integer value of the number of +1 particles on that spot since I need that for my probabilities.

If I want to run something serious like `m=400`, `r=3`, `j=300000` (j: final time) I'm looking at about 4 years of runtime with my current speed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did this in my physics undergrad. It's pretty cool. One thing I would recommend is generating all your random numbers outside any loops. If you're going to need 1000 random numbers generate a 1000-tuple of numbers before you begin your time steps.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988494/efficient-way-to-generate-and-use-millions-of-random-numbers-in-python) discusses fast random number gen.

Comment: Improvements of working code can also be on topic for [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but make sure [it's welcome there](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) if you ask there.

Comment: As for your question, having listcomps and zips and string operations mixed in with numpy is a good sign that your code can probably be improved a lot.

Comment: @wrkyle in the comments of the accepted answer i see what i already feared, running out of RAM. for the big run i mentioned at the bottom it will be about 13.5 billion iterations and i need 2 random numbers per iteration.

Comment: There are some issues that can be improved. 1) Don't use global variables if you don't really need them (easier readable code). 2) Don't use lists for things that they are not really intended for. (only if you need a resizeable object). 3) Absolutely don't use something like "num = int(''.join(map(str, results)))" for type conversion!! 4) If you keep your code simple compiling with cython or a jit compiler is much easier.

Comment: @max9111 1) i guess youre talking about the x1, x2, y1, y2 variables? 2) what could be an alternative? 3) i needed to do that because the output was a 1d array and i cant calculate with that

Comment: I will post a suggestion within the next hour...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Monte Carlo simulation**

At first I get rid of the lists, afterwards I used a just in time compiler (numba). Without compilation a get 196s (your version), with compilation I get 0.44s. So there is a improvement of a factor **435** by using a jit-compiler and a few easy optimizations here.

A main advantage is also, that the GIL (global interpreter lock) is released here also. If the code is processor limited and not limited by the memory bandwith, the random numbers can be calculated in another thread while running the simulation in the other (more than one core can be used). This could also improve performance a bit further and would work as follows:

1. Calculate the first chunk of random numbers (Small enough that the whole problem fits easily in the processor cache (at least L3 cache).
2. Start an iteration with that random numbers. While running the iteration another chunk of random numbers is calculated.
3. Repeat (2) until you are done.

**Code**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def calc (m,j,e,r,dt,b,rgrid,mgrid):
    M=m*m
    N = M * r
    i=0
    while i < j:
        # 1. platz aussuchen
        x = np.random.randint(M)  # wähle zufälligen platz aus

        if rgrid[x] != 0:
            i += dt / N

            ########
            # 2. teilchen aussuchen
            #li1 = np.arange(-abs(rgrid[x]), abs(rgrid[x]) + 1, 2)
            #li2 = np.arange(0, abs(rgrid[x]) + 1)

            #li3 = zip(li1, li2)  # list1 und list2 als tupel in list3
            #results = [item[1] for item in li3 if item[0] == mgrid[x]]  # gebe 2. element von tupel aus für passende magnetisierung
            #num = int(''.join(map(str, results)))  # wandle listeneintrag in int um
            #######

            # This should be equivalent
            jj=0 #li2 starts with 0 and has a increment of 1

            for ii in range(-abs(rgrid[x]),abs(rgrid[x])+1, 2):
                if (ii==mgrid[x]):
                    num=jj
                    break

                jj+=1

            spin = 1.0 if np.random.random() < num / rgrid[x] else -1.0

            # 3. ereignis aussuchen
            p = np.random.random()
            p1 = np.exp(- spin * b * mgrid[x] / rgrid[x]) * dt  # flip
            p2 = dt  # hoch
            p3 = dt  # runter
            p4 = (1 - spin * e) * dt  # links
            p5 = (1 + spin * e) * dt  # rechts
            p6 = 1 - (4 + p1) * dt  # nichts


            if p < p6:
                continue
            elif p < p6 + p1:
                #flip()
                mgrid[x] -= 2 * spin 
                continue
            elif p < p6 + p1 + p2:
                #up()
                y = x - m
                if y < 0:  # periodische randbedingung hoch
                    y += m * m
                rgrid[x] -= 1  # [zeile, spalte] masse -1
                rgrid[y] += 1  # [zeile, spalte] masse +1
                mgrid[x] -= spin  # [zeile, spalte] spinänderung alter platz
                mgrid[y] += spin  # [zeile, spalte] spinänderung neuer platz
                continue
            elif p < p6 + p1 + p2:
                #down()
                y = x + m
                if y >= m * m:  # periodische randbedingung unten
                    y -= m * m
                rgrid[x] -= 1
                rgrid[y] += 1
                mgrid[x] -= spin
                mgrid[y] += spin
                continue
            elif p < p6 + p2 + p3:
                #left()
                y = x - 1
                if (y // m) < (x // m):  # periodische randbedingung links
                    y += m
                rgrid[x] -= 1
                rgrid[y] += 1
                mgrid[x] -= spin
                mgrid[y] += spin
                continue
            else:
                #right()
                y = x + 1
                if (y // m) > (x // m):  # periodische randbedingung rechts
                    y -= m
                rgrid[x] -= 1
                rgrid[y] += 1
                mgrid[x] -= spin
                mgrid[y] += spin
                continue
    return (mgrid,rgrid)
```

And now the main function for testing:

```
def main():
    m = 10  # zeilen, spalten
    j = 1000 # finale zeit
    r = 3  # platzdichte
    b = 1.6  # beta
    e = 0.9  # epsilon

    M = m * m  # platzanzahl
    N = M * r  # teilchenanzahl
    dt = 1 / (4 * np.exp(b))  # delta-t
    i = 0

    rgrid = r * np.ones((m, m),dtype=np.int) #don't convert the array build it up with the right datatype  # dichte-matrix, rho = n(+) + n(-)
    magrange = np.arange(-r, r + 1, 2)  # mögliche magnetisierungen [a, b), schrittweite
    mgrid = np.random.choice(magrange, (m, m))  # magnetisierungs-matrix m = n(+) - (n-)

    #Compile the function
    nb_calc = nb.njit(nb.types.Tuple((nb.int32[:], nb.int32[:]))(nb.int32, nb.int32,nb.float32,nb.int32,nb.float32,nb.float32,nb.int32[:], nb.int32[:]),nogil=True)(calc)

    Results=nb_calc(m,j,e,r,dt,b,rgrid.flatten(),mgrid.flatten())

    #Get the results
    mgrid_new=Results[0].reshape(mgrid.shape)
    rgrid_new=Results[1].reshape(rgrid.shape)
```

**Edit**
I have rewritten the code "2.Teilchen aussuchen" and reworked the code so that it works with scalar indices. This gives an additional speed up by a factor of 4.

Comment: num should always be of size 1 since its the numper of spin 1 particles on that spot. im tryin to install numba right now to test it.

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. I would recommend to use Anaconda. https://www.continuum.io/downloads . As for many other python packages, the installation procedure will be easier. (conda install numba)  That's all ;) If you don't want to use anaconda and you are on windows, this site will help http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numba

Comment: got it installed now with anaconda and virtenv on pycharm :D. got a few questions: 1) in the nb_calc line you have (calc) at the end. pycharm marked this as an error and after removing it worked fine. 2) what does the nb_calc line do? 3) why is b not the in calc-function? i added it for now since it gets used in the spin calculation 4) i imported jit from numba and put '@jit' before the 'def calc'. is that what you meant with compilation?

Comment: The nb_calc line does the compilation. You should put that line after the function definition of calc.There are some ways to accomplish the calculation. There are also some good examples on the numba homepage. I forgot b. Njit or jit with noPython you can gain some speed to. It is also beneficial to decorate the types, like it is done in the nb_calc line.

Comment: i need to look into that, seems amazing. the (calc) in the nb_calc line was a mistake? one last question: p6 is the chance to do nothing and it has highest occurence. i check for that first so the next cycle can start immidiately if thats the case. is that significant for saving time if i do trillions or iterations?

Comment: No it is the correct syntax in CPython and works in my Python environment. Call this line after you defined the calc function (I will edit this). This is a example how to get reasonable speed with Python code. To get the most performance I would write the code in plain C and wrap it with Cython. I also want to mention that the random numbers calculation and the iteration process is practically independent. So you can calculate the random numbers on one core, while calculating the iterations on another core.  The main bottleneck is the "# 2. Teilchen aussuchen" to  res.

Comment: i dont think this works to choose the right particle. for 3 particles with (+1), num would be 6. "num = list(range(- start, end, 2)).index(mgrid[x])" works but is a lot slower.

Comment: I have edited the answer, I hope I got it finally right. Does the compilation work for you. With the optimized code I get around 90s with a normal run (calling calc) and about 0.44s when calling the compiled function (nb_calc).

Comment: this works really good! my solutions were all so terribly slow. im calling the main() function after the 2 codes above and get a time of 0.9-1s. i also found a few errors in my code above when chosing the action (sum of the p's). the time difference could be because of my cpu (ryzen 1700 @stock).

Comment: The compilation takes also some time. 0.9-1s is really fast. On my Core i5 3xxxm the compilation alone takes over one second. Please measure the running time of the function here, because if you increase the problem size the compilation time stays the same, but the function time will increase.

Comment: i actually dont know how to do it :D. what i did all the time is put an time.clock at the start and the end and subract those 2 times. reading up on timeit right now

Comment: import time   t1=time.time()    Results=nb_calc(....  print(time.time()-t1)    time.clock should also work, but measure only the time needed in the Results=nb_calc(... line. I am really interested in this, because I am thinking of buying a Ryzen and that's exactly the kind of benchmarks I am interested in.

Comment: im probably way too stupid right now xD. after the arguments of results=nb_calc i put the print(time.time() - t1) with a "," after the last argument. that gives me some errors and the time of 0.56s

Comment: Why do you put a "," after the last argument? But the code works right now? That's the most important thing ;)

Comment: for the time measurements i did "results = nb_calc(m, j, r, b, e, dt, rgrid.flatten(), mgrid.flatten() , print(time.time() - t2)). i thought thats what you wrote above. code works really good.