# How to generate random placement and trajectory inside of polygon in vectorized way?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a random placement and a random trajectory inside of a polygon. To speed up computation I am looking to do it in vectorized way (using Numpy).

I created code for it if we have square boundaries:

```
import numpy as np
# coordinates of square
square_coords = [-255, -255, 256, 256] # [xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax]
# convert to np.array
square_boundaries = np.array([(square_coords[0], square_coords[2]), (square_coords[1], square_coords[3])])

# specify speeds with corresponding probabilities of each speed
ue_speed = [3, 4, 8, 25] 
ue_speed_prob = [0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1] # should sum up to 1

steps = 50
time_interval = 10
nwalks = 1

# calcultation without boundaries
v = np.random.choice(ue_speed, size=steps, p=ue_speed_prob)
R = np.expand_dims((v * time_interval), axis=-1)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(nwalks, steps)
xy = np.dstack((np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta))) * R
trajectory_no_boundaries = np.hstack((np.zeros((nwalks, 1, 2)), np.cumsum(xy, axis=1)))

# generete random placement inside of boundaries
start = (np.random.randint(square_coords[0], square_coords[2]), np.random.randint(square_coords[1], square_coords[3]))
# generate random trajectory inside of boundaries
size = np.diff(square_boundaries, axis=1).ravel()
trajectory = np.abs((trajectory_no_boundaries[0] + start - square_boundaries[:, 0] + size) % (2 * size) - size) + square_boundaries[:, 0]
```

I am trying to understand if it is possible to transform this code if we have polygon coordinates instead of square coordinates e.g.:

```
polygon_coords = [(100, 100), (80, 130), (90, 130), (90, 140), (70, 140), (150, 200), (120, 150), (100, 100)]
```

To give an idea of how this polygon looks like here is a visualization with Shapely:

```
from shapely import geometry
shapely_polygon_coords = [geometry.Point(coord) for coord in polygon_coords]
geometry.Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in shapely_polygon_coords])
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Just for me to understand it better: does the example with the square have periodic boundaries?

Comment: The only strategy that is reasonable for obtaining points inside an complex arbitrary domain like this is to generate them uniformly in the bounding box, reject those outside and retry.  I don't understand what you want from the trajectory.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman one example where looking at the trajectory might be interesting is in the context of some physical phenomena, like diffusion through a porous medium.

Comment: I understand what a trajectory is. I just have no idea what this trajectory is supposed to interact with the now non-periodic domain. This can't be a question of expanding the current code to a new geometry anymore. Other questions also arise, like why is the position a random *integer*? Nothing else seems to be.

Comment: @AdrianUsler I am not sure if I understand what 'periodic boundaries' mean. Boundaries are fixed but to calculate `trajectory` I am wrapping a trajectory in case it goes out of boundaries so it stays inside of the boundaries all the time. I guess you can say that boundaries are periodic

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I didn't get your first question. Regarding "position as a random integer": I use an integer just as an example. Float is fine as well.

Comment: @illluminato so you're wrapping it in such a way that, e.g., if you were to leave the square box to the right, you come in again on the left side, right? I think it might be difficult to define this in the case of the polygon. Or do you just want to reject a step if the trajectory leaves the box?

Comment: @AdrianUsler if you were to leave the square box to the right, we come in again on the right side. So we simply "unroll" space, so we can simulate an unconstrained random walk which is cheap and then in the end we fold it back to the bounding rectangle.

Comment: @illuminato Can the path of a step in the trajectory cross the polygon border as long as the step itself (point) ends up back within the border?  If not, I don't think it will be possible to simplify in any meaningful way.

Comment: With the square, you know that: **a)** Every point is accessible from every other point without crossing the square's border. **b)** You can use the `%` operator (as you've done) to transform coordinates back into the square (or rectangle) because all _y_ values exist for all _x_ values.  With the polygon, I think you'd need to **1)** Transform one coordinate to be within its range. **2)** Find the range(s) of the other coordinate that exist for that value of the first coordinate _**and**_ that are "visible" from the previous step.

Comment: In some cases, there may not be any visible points at a specified value, so you'd need to try and pick a new point.  For example, imagine your "Point 1" is the top-left point (lowest _x_ value, highest _y_ value) in a U-shaped polygon.  For "Point 2", the algorithm picks a new _x_ value that is equal to the maximum _x_ value for the polygon.  There doesn't exist a _y_ value for which you could reach "Point 2" from "Point 1" without crossing the gap in the polygon, so you'd need to try a new _x_ value, then repeat as needed, which would be quite inefficient!