# Quickly create 2 large random matrices and multiply them

Tags: python, numpy

I have very little experience in Python but I want to do some quick tests before diving in deeper. I have installed Python 3.3 on my Windows (64-bit) machine. I have also installed 'numpy-MKL-1.7.0rc1.win-amd64-py3.3.‌exe' (NumPy) from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

With all of this set up, I basically want to create  two large matrices (10000 x 10000) of random values between 0.0 and 1.0 and multiply them and perhaps time the entire operation.

Using the code here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710189/928007 yielded in the error 'NameError: name 'np' is not defined'

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in that answer requires the following import:

```
import numpy as np
```

This statement needs to be executed before any code that refers to `np.<whatever>`.

Comment: I had to do a bit more digging but your answer helped me. Thanks!